# Extend ToolTip Duration On Linked Map

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I am using latest Highmaps and am trying to create a page with 2 (or more) maps on it. Rendering the maps is fine. The issue is when I am trying to link the tooltips among all maps. I have set up a basic example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/2smou4xp/). My issue is that the non-primary map's tooltip fades out after some time (`tooltip.hideDelay`). I do not want to increase the `hideDelay` as it will also need to be applied to all charts (which will cause tooltips to stay around far too long on the "primary" map that the user is hovering over).

**How can I make the tooltip on any secondary map stay visible until such time as the user does `mouseOut` on the map they are interacting with?**

My code to link the tooltips is as follows:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        //get this map's selected shape:
                        var selGeoID = this.properties.code_hasc;

                        //set up other chart's pointers:
                        var otherChart = $('#container2').highcharts();
                        var otherData = (otherChart.series[0].data);

                        //find this map's shape ID in the other chart's shapes:
                        var arrayData = $.grep(otherData, function (e) {
                            return e.code_hasc == selGeoID;
                        });

                        //if we have a match then loop through all points in
                        //other map to set tooltip on/off:
                        if (arrayData.length == 1) {
                            newIndex = arrayData[0].index;
                            otherData.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
                                if (arrayItem.index != newIndex) {
                                    arrayItem.setState();
                                    otherChart.tooltip.hide();
                                } else {
                                    otherData[newIndex].setState('hover');
                                    otherChart.tooltip.refresh(otherData[newIndex]);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    //clear tooltips on other chart:
                    mouseOut: function () {
                        var otherChart = $('#container2').highcharts();
                        var otherData = (otherChart.series[0].data);
                        otherData.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
                            arrayItem.setState();
                            otherChart.tooltip.hide();
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Do you want the tooltip from the bottom chart to stop hiding while a tooltip is visible in the top chart?

Comment: @KacperMadej Correct. As long as the user is over a point in the "main" map where a tooltip shows then the secondary map's tooltip should show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent tooltip in the second chart from hiding, do not call `tooltip.hide()` in line 86 of your JS code in the JSFiddle.

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1fq9jh0e/

Comment: It is always the simple things.